# Excel VBA to move data from a table in one sheet to a table in another sheet on a new row

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook with two worksheets which both have identical tables. I am looking for VBA to move data from the table in sheet1 to a new available row on the table in sheet2 and delete the moved data from sheet1.

The first sheet is titled "SL Current TCG" and the table named SL_TCG
The second sheet is titled "SL Past TCGs" and the table named SL_Past_TCGs

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am new to VBA by the way!

I have the following that moves the data but I would like the data to go onto a new row on the table in the second sheet not replace the date each time which is what I am getting currently whenever it is run:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim sh3Col As Integer

Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("SL Past TCGs")

Set copySheet = Worksheets("SL Current TCG")
copySheet.Range("SL_TCG").Copy Destination:=pasteSheet.Range("SL_Past_TCGs").Cells(1)

With pasteSheet
    sh3Col = .Range("SL_Past_TCGs").Cells(1).Column
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, sh3Col).End(xlUp).Row
End With

copySheet.Range("SL_TCG").Delete

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Move the block `With pasteSheet`...`End With` after `Set copySheet = Worksheets("SL Current TCG")`, then change the following line to `copySheet.Range("SL_TCG").Copy Destination:=pasteSheet.Range("SL_Past_TCGs").Cells(LastRow, 1)`.